# how to setup an accumulator variable?

Tags: python

First of all, I am writing a code to print inventory of Ikea from a file that has lines like this,
F,301.841.73,**9.99**,HOLMÖ,Floor lamp - gives a soft mood light,*none*,75,116,22,2.2

where the third one "9.99" is the price of that furniture item. i have getter and setter for the price variable as well.

```
def setPrice(self, f_price):
    self.__price = f_price

def getPrice(self):
    return self.__price
```

there is main class called **Furniture** and other sub-classes for items like "BED", "NIGHTSTAND", "ARMCHAIR" etc..

there is a UNIT test framework for these classes. where it creates a list, them opens the file and using loop , it adds all the variables for furniture item like type, an article number, a price, a Swedish-sounding name, a basic description, and optionally, a colour from Furniture class as well as sub variables from sub class to list.

then, AT last, we need to count Total value of inventory. where I initialized a Total_value variable to 0.

```
total_value = 0

for furniture_item in inventory:
    print(str(furniture_item)) # print the item
    print("="*30) # print a separator
    # ADD THE PRICE OF THE ITEM TO THE ACCUMULATOR VARIABLE
    total_value += (value)
```

when I try to get price from getPrice function:

```
price = Furniture.getPrice
    total_value += price
```

it gives me error like this:

```
*****Error***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__tester__.python3", line 212, in <module>
      total_value += price
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'function'**
```

when i do like this:

```
Furniture.getPrice = price
    total_value += price
```

It gives me the value of `**Total Inventory Value: 3184.0**`. But, the value expected is `**Total Inventory Value: 1432.91**`, I don't know what wrong I am doing.

If anyone can suggest to me how to get this expected value, that would be great!!!

Comment: what is `(value)`?

Comment: i was just using a different name than price, it is for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want

```
total_price += furniture_item.getPrice()
```

Comment: Thank you So much !!! it worked. Btw how did you know that? what was I doing wrong?

Comment: first,`getPrice` is a function, and you were missing the parentheses (that was the source of your orginal error message).  Second, `getPrice` is an instance method, so you have to use the `furniture_item` method to get to it, and not the `Furniture` class.

Comment: Ohh, that's why I couldn't get it. that makes sense. I was trying to call `getPrice` function forgetting `furniturre.item` method.